# LWC issues in Winter'20 Sandbox

Tags: lightning-web-components

We are using a Lightning Web Component which is being called on clicking a House Icon on the Lightning Page. 
This House icon is residing inside a Aura Component of minimum dimensions.Whenever i am calling this Web component from Lightning Console App, I am getting small blank screen. This LWC is displayed in Slds modal container and this modal is called from Aura component.

I am getting this issue after Sandbox got upgraded to Winter'20 Release, earlier it was working fine. Please let me know the steps to resolve this issue.

Relevant Code in Aura Component:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">
    <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal--large">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                  onclick="{! c.closeModalLWC }"
                                  alternativeText="close"
                                  variant="border-inverse"
                                  class="slds-modal__close"
                                    />
            <!--<h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">{!v.heading}</h2>-->
            </header> 
            <div class="slds-modal__content">
                <!--LWC Component-->
                <c:opportunityLWC recordId="{!v.recordId}" currOpp="{!v.opp}" onmodalclose="{!c.closeModalLWC}"/>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>               
 </aura:if>   
</aura:if>
```

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: Can you add the relevant code at each step?

Comment: I have posted code in the above question, as i couldn't enter here which was forcing me to enter on 153 charcters here

Comment: Are you seeing any Javascript errors in the browser console?

Comment: I am seeing an error stating "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Any work around on this issue?

Comment: I guess some issue in calling slds_modal_container in Winter'20 Release

Answer (score 0):

Opened a case with Salesforce regarding this issue and they told me it's going to be fixed with the Winter '20 Patch 6.0 on Tuesday, Sept. 17, 2019.

Comment: Thanks for the update Mark that would be great if Salesforce resolve that issue. For now i was able to resolve this issue as mentioned in my earlier comment. But couldn't see an option to select my comment was an answer to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by moving some part of code from  component. The main issue was i am displaying the House Icon and displaying the Slds_Modal_Container after clicking the House icon under  . After moving the code of displaying modal container out of lightning card the issue got resolved. This issue is only happening when we are using this under Lightning console apps under Winter'20. Refer to the below link releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/…